# Error within my jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I was just wondering if I could get some assistance, I have dwelled on this for hours and have a feeling I'm forgetting something basic that maybe an extra pair of eyes can help me with

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.center = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            hasParent: false,
            leftoffset: 0,
            topoffset: 0
        }, options );       

        return this.each(function(){    
            var parent;

            if (settings.hasParent) {
                parent = $(this).parent();
            } else {
                parent = window;
            }

            $(this).css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": ((($(parent).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +      $(parent).scrollTop() + settings.topoffset + "px"),
                "left": ((($(parent).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + settings.leftoffset + "px")
            });
        });             
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The above is the plugin that I have created, but am unable to see an error in, although I am only getting errors in Internet Explorer saying the following

> Object doesn't support property or method 'center'

I call this plugin with the following code

```
$(".center").center({hasParent: true});
```

UPDATE:

Index File that uses the script

```
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "asset/shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src = "asset/center.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $ = jQuery.noConflict();

            $("#container").css("height", $(window).height() + "px");
            $("#container").css("width", $(window).width() + "px");

            $(".center").center({hasParent: true});


            $(".center").children().css("opacity", 0);
            $(".center").css("visibility", "visible");

            var LogoTop = parseInt($("#Logo").css("top"));
            var LTTop = parseInt($("#LTText").css("top"));
            var CSTop = parseInt($("#ComingSoonText").css("top"));

            $("#Logo").css("top", LogoTop - 500);
            $("#LTText").css("top", LTTop - 500);
            $("#ComingSoonText").css("top", CSTop + 500);

            $("#Logo").animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: LogoTop
            }, 1000, function(){
                $("#LTText").animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: LTTop
                }, 750);

                $("#ComingSoonText").animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: CSTop
                }, 750);
            });



            $(window).on("resize", function(){

                $("#container").css("height", $(window).height() + "px");
                $("#container").css("width", $(window).width() + "px");
                $(".center").center({hasParent: true});

            }).trigger('resize');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you using a self-executing function to do this? You don't need it.

Comment: I was taught always create closure if that's the function you are referring to?

Comment: Your seems ok; can you have a previous a missing __;__ at the end of a precedent included function?

Comment: If you are only adding a fn to jQuery I don't see the need of using closures, by the way idk what is wrong, I tried this code on Explorer and works fine.

Comment: Same here.. Code is working fine. I guess jsFiddle will be good

Comment: I updated it to show my index file that uses it, I'm actually blind by something so minor =[ Kinda sad haha. Could it have to do with the noConflict??